# Tags need wikis! Can you help?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

Every tag could (and should!) have a tag wiki and perhaps even more importantly a tag wiki excerpt; this is what you see in the list of tags and when hovering over a tag.

While a fair number of tags have at least a tag wiki excerpt (thanks to everybody that wrote one!) this is not at all the case for all tags. 
And some that do have one, might need an expanded one.

Please, consider writing a tag wiki excerpt and possibly even an actual tag wiki, for some tags you care about.
To write one, go to the tags page, like https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education-research  and click "help us create it" in the first line (if it has none), 
or "Improve tag wiki" towards the top if it has one already.

This thread can be used for general or specific discussions related to this task.

Comment: Possibly I should add that while the point limit to directly edit these wikis is somewhat high, one can do it by suggested edit so everybody could contribute. In case of technical issues please do not hesitate to ask, or just post here and I copy it over.

Comment: I will most likely be over the point limit soon, and will check some of these out at that time.

Comment: @JPBurke That's great news. And, thank you for your continued high-level contributions to the site!

Comment: I wanted to try writing some tag wiki excerpts.  Is it OK to do that without writing the full tag wiki? I know they will be edited by someone else, but you seem to be encouraging contributions and there are a lot of tags without wikis.

Comment: @AmyB yes, this is perfectly fine. Every contribution is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

### A proposed guideline on writing tag wiki excerpts

From the page "[What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)"

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.

Each tag has a "tag wiki" ("tag info") composed of two parts:  a "tag wiki excerpt" ("usage guidance") and a "tag wiki" ("full tag wiki").

From the page "[What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/)"

> Each tag on Stack Exchange has two pieces of user-editable content associated with it:
>
> - a short tag wiki excerpt of up to about 500 characters of plain text, and
> - a full tag wiki page describing the tag in more detail.

From the [Stack Exchange Blog post of Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/):

> The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences.

and

> **Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.** In other words, *what kinds of questions should have this tag?* Tags only exist as ways of organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on which questions *need* this tag, they won’t get tagged at all, rendering the tag excerpt moot.

---

I propose that the tag excerpt should be a phrase that completes the sentence "This tag is for questions that are about […]."

Some examples:

- *precalculus*: "Courses designed to prepare students for subsequent calculus courses"
- *common-core*: "The Common Core State Standards in the United States of America"
- *terminology*: "How words are used in mathematics or mathematics education"
- *bug*: "A reproducible problem on the site that is believed to be due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error"
- *support*: "Seeking help with a feature of the site"
- *status-declined*: "Feature requests that will not be implemented, or bugs that will not be fixed at the present time"
- *duplicate-questions*: "Identifying and closing questions that are duplicates of another question"

Comment: To link to a tag on main, type "\[tag:name-of-tag\]" in your post (for example, [tag:precalculus]).  To link to a tag on meta, type "\[meta-tag:name-of-tag\]" (for example, [meta-tag:bug].